# How long should i wait for clickonce?

Tags: clickonce

May i know is it normal to wait for 10 min for deployment using clickone?
I am using some third parties .dll which are quite large size in my project, does the Clickonce publish those .dll files as well each time i publish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how it's configured, but by default it should also upload all dll's every time.

Answer (score 0):

When publishing, it does publish all of the dll's every time. How large is your whole deployment?

You can try publishing via FTP or to a file share instead of using HTTP. If you can publish with FTP, set the publishing file location to the FTP url (like ftp://myaddress.myserver.com/myapp), and set the installation URL to the HTTP url (like http://myaddress.myserver.com/myapp).

Fyi, when installing, it caches any strongly named dll's on the client machine. When updates are installed, it checks each of those dll's to see if they have changed, and if they have not, it retrieves them from the cache instead of copying them from the server again.

So you take the hit when publishing, but your customer doesn't.